# Address book similar to BibTeX to be used on LyX

Tags: bibtex, xetex, lyx, addresses

I have a list of addresses. While writing the report (not in letter), I need to add address repeatedly. Is their something similar to BibTeX, which I can use with LyX for automating inclusion of required person's address in a LyX document. Note that If I use BibTeX for it, LyX automatically puts *References* section and starts below it. I need to put the addresses at place of my choice. eg

> Kindly contact Mr X at this address: 143, St Jaferson road, XXX.

Comment: I don't know LyX, but this sounds like a job for either [datatool](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) or [csvsimple](http://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple).  But how easily they can be used in (with?) LyX is unclear to me....

Comment: There are a few options for such things in "Insert > File" in LyX. For example, Insert File > Child Document.